# Calling of <aop:aspectj-autoproxy /> multiple times when loading spring context

Tags: java, spring, aspectj

Let's say I am defining a custom aspect and to enable proxying I am using `aop:aspectj-autoproxy`. Now I am also importing another third-party spring context in the application that also happens to call `aop:aspectj-autoproxy` (ofcourse I won't know about it upfront unless I pore over the context xml contents extracted from the JAR). Potentially there can be many such contexts. Here I see that the beans matching the pointcut get proxied over and over i.e. proxy of a proxy. Is there a way that one can avoid such a proxy of a proxy? Also feel free to point out any anti-patterns that may be at play here.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Spring documentation:

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.6.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-proxying

> Note Multiple  sections are collapsed into a single
>   unified auto-proxy creator at runtime, which applies the strongest
>   proxy settings that any of the  sections (typically from
>   different XML bean definition files) specified. This also applies to
>   the tx:annotation-driven and aop:aspectj-autoproxy elements.
>
> To be clear: using 'proxy-target-class="true"' on
>   ,  or 
>   elements will force the use of CGLIB proxies for all three of them

Comment: The multiple proxying was happening because I had multiple advices in the context. As mentioned by Ramesh, the framework itself is immune to multiple declarations with the strongest one taking precedence

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem mainly relates to

> Now I am also importing another third-party spring context in the application that also happens to call aop:aspectj-autoproxy

Instead of directly importing the app ctx provided by 3rd party lib (which is, in most case, provided for ease of initial development or for small project), try to manage those 3rd party beans in your own app ctx, and make sure you do not have multiple aop:aspectj-autoproxy  (There are lots of bean post-processor etc in spring that is not safe in multiple declaration.)

Comment: It is not really the app ctx but rather the service context which is ensuring that the beans that are going to be used by the JAR classes are correctly wired and have their dependencies managed. Apache CXF uses something similar `<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" />`